# POIXMLException while writing to an .xlsx file

Tags: java, file, apache-poi, xlsx, fileoutputstream

Recently I have been trying to write to an .xlsx file. My code is from tutorial where it is working perfectly. In my case it is not. The file is created but with no sheet called "Devnami" and the words "invoice" and "date" are not there also.  Why is that happening? I don't know if that changes something but I am using LibreOffice Calc for .xlsx files. Here is my code:

```
private void gexcel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\CA_LTD\\Desktop\\excelfile.xlsx"));
        XSSFSheet Spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("Devnami");
        Spreadsheet.getRow(1).createCell(0).setCellValue("invoice");
        Spreadsheet.getRow(1).createCell(1).setCellValue("date");
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println("Excel file created");

}
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Excel file created
```

Comment: What's the full stacktrace? That bit doesn't really tell us anything...

Comment: That's everything

Comment: Instead of `System.out.println(e);` do `e.printStackTrace();` to  get the full stacktrace. But what I can tell frorm code viewing is that `Spreadsheet.getRow(1).createCell(0).setCellValue("invoice");` would must throw `NullPointerExcedption` because `Spreadsheet.getRow(1)` will return `null` when `Spreadsheet` is a new created `Sheet`. A new created sheet does not contain any rows. They must first be created using `createRow`.

Comment: Btw.: `Java` variable names should not start uppercase. Names starting uppercase are class names according to naming convention. So your `Spreadsheet` should be `spreadsheet`.